# How to animate layout like this picture

Tags: android, user-interface, polling

want animate layout like this picture
https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/430056/screenshots/2187521/luna.gif
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipoOC.jpg
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://kylewbanks.com/blog/left-and-right-slide-animations-on-android-activity-or-view

Answer (score 1):

Create anim folder in res

enter_bottom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0%p" />
</set>
```

enter_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

enter_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

enter_top.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0%p" />
</set>
```

exit_bottom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="100%p" />
</set>
```

exit_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

exit_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

exit_top.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="-100%p" />

</set>
```

Use something like this when you start an activity or finish::

```
Intent skip = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(skip);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_top, R.anim.exit_bottom);
```

When finish

```
finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_right, R.anim.exit_left);
```